# Using lambda to send html files is producing syntax errors but only sometimes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lambda

Edit: So I was messing around with the dev tools when I noticed that in the network the page only won't load when my .ico image isn't sent, maybe theres something wrong with that.

I'm sort of new to using react and very new to using Lambda / API gateway and all that. I've been running into an issue where sometimes my website gives a syntax error such as:

SyntaxError: missing name after . operator

or

SyntaxError: missing name after : operator

but if I keep refreshing it might give another error, or the website will just load. Sometimes it will not load the css, or other times something else will not load properly. It can take up to 2-3 refreshes to get the website to the full state.

And yes there is a valid reason why i'm not using API gateway to handle all this for me.

Any ideas?

The code is a little messy but should be readable.

I'm not really sure where to even begin debugging something like this. All the lambda function does is open the s3 bucket, get the compiled css / js files that react made and sends it to whoever made the request.

```
if(event.path === '/')
  {
    let bucket = process.env.CODE_S3_BUCKET;
    let key = path.join(process.env.ADDITIONAL_ARTIFACTS_S3_PATH, 'index.html');

    let dataBody; 

    var params = {
      Bucket: bucket,
      Key: key
    };

    return s3.getObject(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error getting object: ' + bucket + ':' + key);
      } else {

        dataBody = data.Body.toString();

        callback(null, {
          statusCode: 200,
          isBase64Encoded: false,
          body: dataBody,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html'
          }
        });
      }
    }).promise();
  }
  else
  {

    let bucket = process.env.CODE_S3_BUCKET;
    let key = path.join(process.env.ADDITIONAL_ARTIFACTS_S3_PATH, event.path);

    let mimeType = mime.lookup(key);

    let dataBody; 

    var params = {
      Bucket: bucket,
      Key: key
    };


// Checks if its in the included file types

    if(textMimes.includes(mimeType))
    {

      return s3.getObject(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error('Error getting object: ' + bucket + ':' + key);
        } else {

          dataBody = data.Body;

          callback(null, {
            statusCode: 200,
            isBase64Encoded: false,
            body: dataBody.toString(),
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': mimeType
            }
          });
        }
      }).promise();

    } else {

      return s3.getObject(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error('Error getting object: ' + bucket + ':' + key);
        } else {

          dataBody = data.Body;

          callback(null, {
            statusCode: 200,
            isBase64Encoded: true,
            body: dataBody.toString('base64'),
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': mimeType
            }
          });
        }
      }).promise();

    }
```

Comment: Yeah lol like I said, am new to most of this and had some issues when putting some stuff into separate functions. Its just test code though, plan on fixing all these code repeats and stuff later. edit: Response to comment saying lots of code repeats ^.^

Comment: Wanted to come back to answer this; How it was fixed but there was an issue with the way the callback was being handled. All I changed was I made it use a different format of callback (I think instead of .promise I used another callback form). I'm not a javascript expert so I can't comment on what the reason for this was.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but maybe this version will make it easier for you to think about important parts and not concentrate on repeats:

```
const is_at_root = event.path === '/';
const s3_params = {
        Bucket: process.env.CODE_S3_BUCKET,
        Key: path.join(process.env.ADDITIONAL_ARTIFACTS_S3_PATH, is_at_root ? event.path : 'index.html')
    };
const mime_type = mime.lookup(key);
const requires_base64 = textMimes.includes(mime_type);
const callback_params = {
    statusCode: 200,
    isBase64Encoded: requires_base64,
    body: requires_base64 ? data.Body.toString('base64') : data.Body.toString(),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': requires_base64 ? mime_type : 'text/html'
    }
}

return s3.getObject(s3_params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Error getting object: ' + s3_params.Bucket + ':' + s3_params.Key);
    } else {
        callback(null, callback_params);
    }
}).promise();
```